# Calculate the 'center of an array' in Java

Tags: java, arrays, center

this is my question:

Given an  int array of length=6, i'd would like to know which pair of numbers that belongs to the array, is the center of it. That means that if you divide the array into 3 smalls arrays of length==2, and if you put them as single pair of coordinates in a matrix, (where the first coordinate means the value of the i, and the second one means the value of the j), you would get something like an "L", on your matrix. So, the center is the small coordinate of length=2 that's in the midle of the L. I know it's pretty confusing, so here's an image:

[image: grid]

PD: the only pair of "small arrays" available are:

```
{array[0],array[1]}

{array[2],array[3]}

{array[4],array[5]}
```

Hope you can help me! I'm making the logic of a game! Sorry for my English!

Comment: What do you want the input and output to be?

Comment: So every two numbers in the array define a coordinate on a plane, and you want to find the tuple that is the physical center within that plane? It's a little unclear what you're asking for?

Comment: This question is incomprehensible.

Comment: Your example is wrong ! your array should be `|0|0|0|1|1|0|`

Comment: I made a mistake on the image, sorry. The coordinates would be {0,0,0,1,1,0}

You re right Nathaniel, that's what i'm looking for!

Comment: You have incorrectly specified an array of 6 integers, through comment from @NathanielFord, you have confirmed that what you actually have is an array of 3 containing sets of {x,y} coordinates ie {{x,y},{x,y},{x,y}}, for which you want to find the geometric centre.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is wrong ! your array should be `|0|0|0|1|1|0|`

A simple way to check it would be :

```
|0|1|2|   3   |    4  |5| 
|x|y|x|y(+/-)1|x(+/-)1|y|
or
|0|1|   2   |3|4|    5  |
|x|y|x(+/-)1|y|x|y(+/-)1|
```

***To check if the center is c(x=0,y=1) :***

check if same value of x (index 0) is in index 2 and equal to (value in index 4 (+/-)1) **AND**  if same value of y (index 1) is in index 3 and equal to (value in index 5 (+/-)1)

**OR** check if same value of x (index 0) is in index 4 and equal to (value in index 2 (+/-)1) **AND**  if same value of y (index 1) is in index 5 and equal to (value in index 3 (+/-)1)

PS. in the above case I fixed the L length to 1 you can change that and use another value 4, 5 etc.

Comment: Great! but i think that way just proves that the array has the geometric shape of an L, but how do I find the center of the L ?

Comment: if your check succeeds that means first point x=value in index 0, y = value in index =1  is the center

Comment: @user2970305 did you try that logic?

Answer (score 1):

When the given three co-ordinates of the cells form "L" shape, two cells will be opposite to each other. That is those two cells will have points like (a,b) and (b,a). So the point other than these two will become the center.

So simply find the two points which are like (a,b) and (b,a). The other point will be the center.

if First, second and three are three points of the form (a,b)
something like

```
if(first.a==second.b && first.b=second.a)

        return three;

if(second.a==three.b && second.b==three.a)


     return first;

else return second;
```

Comment: Not correct. They will be the same +/- an offset, which in the case provided, because it starts at 0,0 would be 0-0 = 0. If the L points in a different direction you would have to test each of the four directions as well. (left/up, left/down, right/up, right/down)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, you are given an arbitrary array of length 6 that contains some L-Shape of unknown orientation, and you must return the slice in the array that is the center?

Well, how would we figure out where the center is? It's going to be the x and y coordinate that is repeated twice. So just look for the x value that is repeated twice, then look for your y value that is repeated twice. You now have your center.

Answer (score 0):

first i could not understand your question properly.If what i understood is right then here is soluton.eg:You have an int array of lenght 10.you wanna put every two element in separate array and find the midle array in that order.

So if length of your input array is even then just do (length of array)/2 ,which in our case is 5.Then obviously yur mid array will be the array containing 5 th and 6 th element in the original input array

if length of your input array is odd then just do (length of array+1)/2 ,which in our case is 6.Then obviously yur mid array will be the array containing 6 th and 7 th element in the original input array.But in this case last array wont have jth co-ordinate .

You havenot specified about the lenght of the array.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an array of 3 Points.  A [Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) is a Java class that holds an x and y value.

Your 3 Points shaded red in the illustration would be:

```
0, 1
0, 0
1, 0
```

Another L shaped set of points would be:

```
2, 2
3, 2
3, 1
```

Comment: Sure, the `Point` class is nice to use but that alone doesn't help with answering the question.

Comment: Not really the answer, but this finally challenges the original OP to identify that they have an array of 3 pairs of {x,y}, not an array of 6.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you are just looking for an average:

```
i = (array[0] + array[2] + array[4])/3;
j = (array[1] + array[3] + array[5])/3;
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but does this doesn't point to a tuple in the original array, only finds the geometric 'center' of all provided tuples. Consider `x= {0,0,0,4}`: your solution suggests something like `{0,1.3}`, which isn't in the original array.

Comment: I said that is has to be an array of lenght 6, and your array already is an "L". That means that the array your recieve as a parameter has already the geometric shape of an L!